# using read() to read one char at a time from a file

Tags: c, eof

I would like to be able to read from a file one character at a time using read. I cannot use fgetc. I tried looking for EOF and I can't get it to work. Thanks for your help.

```
char data[1024];
int infile = open(inFileName, O_RDONLY);
if(infile < 0 ) return 1;

int *c = '\0';
int i = 0;
for(i =0; i<30;++i){
   read(infile, &c, 1);
   printf("%c\n", c);
   if(c == EOF){
       break;
     }
}
```

Comment: The first thing to do will be to read the documentation of `read()`...

Comment: I bet the call to read crashes when it tries to write into the buffer that you gave it as the second parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` does not return `EOF` if there is no more input. `read` normally returns the number of bytes read. Since you are intending to read only one byte, you expect `read` to return `1`. When it returns `0`, it means it has reached the end. If it returns `-1`, it means it encountered an error, and you should check `errno` for more information.

Your program has other issues. Your use of `int *c` is completely wrong. Since `data` is already defined, you can use that to read the file, even if you only intend to use only the first byte of the buffer. You should check to see if input was actually obtained before attempting to print it.

```
char data[1024];
int infile = open(inFileName, O_RDONLY);
if(infile < 0 ) {
    perror(inFileName);
    return 1;
}

int i = 0;
for(i =0; i<30;++i){
   int r = read(infile, data, 1);
   if(r <= 0){
       if (r < 0) perror("read");
       break;
     }
   printf("%c\n", data[0]);
}
```